# set default font family as Helvetica in menu bar in tinymce on load

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Can anyone tell me how to set the font-family for tinymce as helvetica by default in the menu bar. [image]

I am using Tinymce 3.5.6 version?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try `tinyMCE.init({
    setup : function(ed){
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed){
            ed.getDoc().body.style.fontFamily="helvetica";
        });
    },`

Comment: I didnt get anything,i was added above code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the StyleFormats option in tinyMCE init

```
style_formats: [
        {
            title: 'Text',
            inline: 'p',
            styles: {                
                font: 'normal normal normal 12px Helvetica, sans-serif'
            }
        }
```

This will make the text in all paragraphs to be Helvetica. If you need more options you can check the documentation here:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:style_formats

They also have demo of custom style formats here:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php